# how to handle the async data in vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous

I have the deman to fetch the server data and then process before rendering the page.
here is the code in my `index.vue`, in option api:

```
<template>
 <div>{{userData.name}}</div>// 'helloworld'
 <div>{{testName}}</div>// ❌'undefined'
</template>
<script>
import {ref} from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

export default{
 setup(){
  const userData=ref([])
  const testName = ref('')
  oNmounted(async ()=>{
     const res=await axios({url:'/myProfile',method:'get'})
   })
   userData.value=res.data.data //here I can get the async data after the Internet time travel.

   //in other func to process the `userData` object which would be `[{name:'helloWorld',...}]
   testName.value = userData.name
   cosole.log(userData.name) //output `undefined`, but if i refer it in the template section, it works.
 }
 
 return {
  userData,
  testName,
 }
}

</script>
```

I want to process the async data before it is rendered, how can I make sure that I could obtain the fetched data to use in the `<script>` section instead of `<template>` section?
And the `userData` I defined is a `ref`, in the beginnig of the async fetch, it is assumed to be `undefined`, but after the async axios, the `userData` is assinged to the latest target value I want, then why they won't be updated accordingly?
what am I missing in this fulfillment?

Comment: What does `oNmounted ` do? I suspect `setup` needs to be marked as `async` and the Axios request `await`ed. But I am not familiar with Vue.js.

Comment: it's a typo, it should be `onMounted` instead. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `userData` as a ref (see https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref)

```js
const userData = ref([])
```

When you want to access the value of userData **inside your code block**, you need to use the property `.value` to points to the inner value.
If access is in the **template tag**, don't use the `.value` property.

So the corrected line would be :

```js
testName.value = userData.value.name
```